# How to resolve "Delphi style classes have to be derived from Delphi style classes"?

Tags: c++, delphi, c++builder

If I have a class defined as :

```
// foo.h
class Foo
{
public:
    virtual void GetFoo();
}
```

And I want a `TForm` to inherit from it, for example

```
class TFMainWindow : public TForm, public Foo
{
   ...
}
```

I get the error

> [bcc32c Error] TFMainWindow.h(36): Delphi style classes have to be derived from Delphi style classes

How do I rsolve this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`TForm` derives from [`TObject`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.TObject), which is a "Delphi-style class", ie it is implemented in Delphi pascal, not in C++.  in Delphi, `TObject` is the root of all class object instances.

Delphi does not support multiple inheritance of classes, like C++ does.  Only single inheritance.  A Delphi class can have only 1 base class at most.  But, it can implement multiple *interfaces*.

So, in C++Builder, when a C++ class has `TObject` as an ancestor, any other non-base ancestors MUST be *interfaces* only, which your `Foo` is not. An *interface* in this case is any class that has no data members, and only *pure virtual* methods and `__property` declarations are allowed.

If `Foo::GetFoo()` were a *pure virtual* method instead, then your code would work as expected, eg:

```cpp
class Foo
{
public:
    virtual void GetFoo() = 0;
};

class TFMainWindow : public TForm, public Foo
{
    ...
public:
    void GetFoo();
    ...
};
```

This is simply a limitation of how C++ and Delphi interact with each other.

This is documented behavior:

[C++ and Delphi Class Models: Inheritance and Interfaces](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Inheritance_and_Interfaces)

> Unlike C++, the Delphi language does not support multiple inheritance. Any classes that you create that have RTL ancestors inherit this restriction. That is, you can not use multiple base classes for a Delphi style C++ class, even if the RTL class is not the immediate ancestor.
>
> ### Using Interfaces Instead of Multiple Inheritance
>
> For many of the situations where you would use multiple inheritance in C++, Delphi code makes use of interfaces instead. There is no C++ construct that maps directly to the Delphi concept of interface. An Delphi interface acts like a class with no implementation. That is, an interface is like a class where all the methods are pure virtual and there are no data members. While an Delphi class can have only a single parent class, it can support any number of interfaces. Delphi code can assign a class instance to variables of any of those interface types, just as it can assign the class instance to a variable of any ancestor class type. This allows polymorphic behavior for classes that share the same interface, even if they do not have a common ancestor.
>
> In C++Builder, the compiler recognizes classes that have only pure virtual methods and no data members as corresponding to Delphi interfaces. Thus, when you create a Delphi style class, you are permitted to use multiple inheritance, but only if all of the base classes except the one that is a RTL or Delphi style class have no data members and only pure virtual methods.
>
> Note: The interface classes do not need to be Delphi style classes; the only requirement is that they have no data members and only pure virtual methods.

Differences in object models between Delphi and C++ is also why C++ classes that are derived from `TObject` [MUST be constructed in dynamic memory with `new`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/E2459_Delphi_style_classes_must_be_constructed_using_operator_new_(C%2B%2B)), even though C++ normally allows classes to be constructed in static/automatic memory without the use of `new`.

Comment: Ah! That was exceptionally easy! Thanks! I never used Delphi (neither do I plan to) but I have used Java and C# for years, so I am familiar with the inheritance principles, here. :)